# Cant get around an OLE DB error

Tags: excel, asp-classic, oledb, xls

I am currently getting the following error:

> Microsoft OLE DB Service Components error '80040e73'
>
> Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification.

My code is as follows with the variable `ExportPath` being created on the fly to create unique `XLS` names. e.g. `D:\RiskCheck\Website\demo\newsite\exports\Reporting_Export_NTQ0KZZU0T262014115941.xls`

```
set cnn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source="&ExportPath&";" & _
          "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';"
```

This issue has been driving me absolutely mental all morning and numerous fixes found across Google haven't been successful, any advice rather welcome!

Comment: Did you try to put the data source parameter in single quotes too? `Data Source='"&ExportPath&"';"`

Comment: You have a single quote after HDR=YES;. This single quote is the only difference you have compared to [Microsofts example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326548) so my guess is that's your problem.